# Enter key is not working for kendo-upload while using JAWS screen reader

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, accessibility, kendo-upload

I'm having `kendo-upload` in my application. Keyboard accessibility is working perfectly without `JAWS`. With `JAWS` the upload button is not keyboard accessible.

Note : We can't use `role=application` it will make up/down arrow not to work.

Is there any other way to make it keyboard accessible with `JAWS`.

sample code

[image]

Raised an issue in telerik :
https://github.com/telerik/kendo-angular/issues/3564

To reproduce the issue :
https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/uploads/upload/keyboard-navigation/
Or
https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/uploads/fileselect/keyboard-navigation/
[image]

Expected behavior::
Enter key press should work with JAWS tool (or)

Screen reader should read press alt+enter instead of enter.
Why Because alt+enter is working

Comment: Does it work with NVDA?  What happens if you toggle forms mode (Ins+space)?  After toggling, does ENTER work?

Comment: Hi @revathi, welcome to SO, please provide your code into code snippets to help you better and take a look at why this is important. [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: @slugolicious i didn't check with NVDA am using only JAWS tool. After toggling also enter is not working.

Comment: In description I have updated the issue reproduction link and inspected code image also.

Comment: Enter key press is not working for kendo-upload button with JAWS tool.
Alt+Enter alone working but screen reader reading like Press Enter to activate.
I guess tabindex="-1" is there for input tag. This is causing the issue. I inspected in console and tried to change tabindex to 0 then it is working

Comment: Expected behavior
Enter key press should work with JAWS tool or
Screen reader should read press alt+enter instead of enter.